# Add Eclipse Refactor History to Git Repository

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, push, automated-refactoring

I'm refactoring my Java code in Eclipse, and they are saved in Refactor History. But I need push my project to Bitbucket, and I want that Refactor History push too.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refactoring history is stored in the Workspace meta data in the:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring/.refactorings
```

directory.

I don't think this data is really useful for storing in git.

Comment: Thanks. There are a practice for college, and the teacher didn't want I asked. They want the script in git.